# How to create these type of vectors in R and how to do operations such as calculating mean and covariance?

Tags: r, vector

I'm very new to R and trying to find out if possible to make vectors like these, sorry not sure what they are called.

```
X1={(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)}
X2={(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)}
```

where if I were to calculate mean of X1, for example, it would be

```
(1/3)[(1,2)+(2,3)+(3,4)]=((1+2+3)/3, (2+3+4)/3)=(2,3)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can create a 3x2 matrix like this:

```
X1 <- matrix(c(1,2,2,3,3,4), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
colMeans(X1) # 2 3
```

...but as you can see (2+3+4)/3 isn't 3.33 ;-)

Note that matrices in R are in column-major order so if you specify it row-by-row you need the `byrow=TRUE` option.

...and for the covariance:

```
X1 <- matrix(c(1,2,2,3,3,4), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
X2 <- matrix(c(0,1,1,2,2,3), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
cov(X1, X2) # covariance
cor(X1, X2) # correlation
```